# Registering a Class Syntax - Swift

Tags: ios, class, swift, init

I'm looking to register my UICollectionViewFlowLayout class via it's init method:

```
class GridLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override init() {
        super.init()

        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical;
        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(187, 273)
        // Register my class here...
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

In Objective C, I would achieve this with the following syntax.

```
[self registerClass:[MyView class] forDecorationViewOfKind:[MyView kind]];
```

Quite a simple question, how do i write this in swift?

**Edit**:
*kind* is a function in MyView Class...

```
func kind() -> NSString {
    return kShelfViewKind
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [prerelease iOS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/navigation/) can show you the Swift syntax for most all objective-c methods you're used to. For this specific case, it's [`func registerClass(_ viewClass: AnyClass!,
forDecorationViewOfKind decorationViewKind: String!)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/registerClass:forDecorationViewOfKind:).

The tricky bit is passing the `viewClass` parameter. The closest equivalent to Objective-C's `[MyView class]` in Swift is: `MyView.self`.

Additionally, your `kind()` function should be a [Type Method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_351) so that you can call it on the class itself and not just on instances of the class:

```
class func kind() -> NSString { ... }
```

After that change, your function call should look like:

```
self.registerClass(MyView.self, MyView.kind());
```

Comment: I apologise, I should have clarified that kind is a convenience method: See my Post Edit